# Sandboxed Cocoa WebView disables Silverlight

Tags: cocoa, silverlight, uiwebview, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

In my OSX app I have a WebView that goes to a page with Silverlight content.  Everything works well in non-sandboxed mode, but as soon as I "sandbox" it the Silverlight content does not load... just a blank WebView.  Has anyone else noticed this?

I have played around with the entitlement file and have enabled everything possible.  Regular web content works fine, but not Silverlight content.  Here are my settings, perhaps someone can offer any suggestions.

```
 <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
 <true/>

 <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
 <true/>

 <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
 <true/>

<!--  Here I tried using the temporary-exception entitlement to point to the Silverlight plugin, but it did not work :(  -->

 <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
 <array>
      <string>/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin/Contents/</string>
      <string>/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin/Contents/MacOS/agcore</string>
      <string>/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin/</string>
      <string>/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin</string>
      <string>/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/</string>
      <string>/Library/Internet Plug-Ins</string>
 </array>

 <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write</key>
 <array>
      <string>/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/</string>
 </array>

 <!--  I read somewhere online to try this but it did not work :(  -->
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name</key>
 <array>
      <string>com.apple.WebKit.PluginAgent</string>
 </array>
```

Do I need to do anything with my code so the Webview sees (and loads) the Silverlight content?  I'm puzzled because it works just fine without sandboxing, but I can't Submit to the Mac App Store unless it works in a sandbox.   Any help would be greatly appreciated... thanks!!!